# Add double quotes to SQL output for columns with spaces

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have three column Person_Number, Name and Address. Now there is a requirement to add double quotes if the particular field has spaces.

How this can be done ?

Comment: This is a weird requirement. A database is supposed to hold the mere data, e.g. `John Smith`. If an app needs `"John Smith"` instead, it should add the quotes itself.

Comment: The requirement is to extract the data with quotes. The Database contains the name without quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INSTR` and `CASE` statement as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN INSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, ' ') > 0 
        THEN '"'
              || YOUR_COLUMN
              || '"'
        ELSE YOUR_COLUMN
    END
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

If you want to update the table then you can use the following query:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET Person_Number = CASE WHEN INSTR(Person_Number,' ')>0
                         THEN '"' || Person_Number || '"' 
                         ELSE Person_Number 
                    END,
    Name = CASE WHEN INSTR(Name,' ')>0 
                THEN '"' || Name || '"' 
                ELSE Name 
           END,
    Address = CASE WHEN INSTR(Address,' ')>0 
                   THEN '"' || Address || '"' 
                   ELSE Address 
              END
WHERE INSTR(Person_Number,' ')>0 
   OR INSTR(Name,' ')>0 
   OR INSTR(Address,' ')>0;
```

Comment: Hello, although the above query shows correct output in a excel file, but when I open the output of the query in notepad then extra double Quotes are added. Do you know why this is happening ?